# what is the best screen resolution to develop web pages?

Tags: firefox, plugins, screen, resolution

I m, on a daily basis creating web pages. My preferred development screen resolution is: 1600x1200 but what is yours?
And do you use any other plug-ins?
I use window re sizer 1.0 for Firefox. But are there better options?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use the largest resolution your monitor can handle?

Comment: @Will - He is talking about usability with other resolutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, if you're using a window resizer, you're already on top of the game.  I try to aim for pages that work well on a 1024x768 screen, accounting for scrollbars and toolbars and whatnot.  It may be worth resizing your screen to 1024x768 (or whatever the minimum is that you support) every once in a while just to fully understand that user experience, but in general the window resizer keeps you aware enough.

Comment: If you're using Windows 7, and you have a standard 1080 HD monitor (1920 x 1080), you can try using the snap feature for the browser window and develop inside of that. Then the page will conform to a 1024x768 screen which is a reasonable low end these days (compared to 800x600). It also fits in with the design purpose of Snap (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snap)  I realize it's been years since this answer so this is an update.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree - fixed size layouts are just fine.  In fact, Stackoverflow.com uses a fixed size layout, as do a great many professional sites out there.  The reason?  *Predictability.*

A few things:

1. **Never** have horizontal scroll bars
2. Try to avoid vertical scroll bars when it's reasonable to do so
3. Remember, AJAX and other newer technologies can help you save space on your page with popups and other niceties.

My 2 cents,

-Doug

Comment: this is not always the case: take a look at some top design firms that use the horizontal scroll bar very efficiently and in an original way. And vertical bars can, in my opinion only be avoid if you have very little information to display... It all depends on the type of website you are creating and personal prefs.

Comment: I'd like to see these design firms that use the horizontal scroll bar - I've never personally seen a site that uses horizontal scroll and simultaneously provides a good user experience.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter - design your web pages to be flexible and fluid such that they degrade gracefully on any reasonable screen resolution. Cater for mobile devices with very minimal screen space and massive displays.

Comment: A good example of "flexible" on any screen resolution to me also would include something that limits size, for people who are more frequently browsing with huge widescreen monitors at 1900x1200, etc. Reading an article that traverses such a wide resolution is bothersome, so limit the max size as well, or perhaps add columns of text. (This is why my browser window generally stays as a square on 2/3 of my wide screen.)

Comment: Indeed the website you design should be limited by a specific resolution, but there is, in my opinion, a huge difference to develop in certain resolutions.

For example, when developing in 800x600 i bet this doesn't look very good on a super wide screen and vice verse. The user should always get a good view, but the developer in my opinion would be better of with a large screen, then a small one.

Answer (score 0):

I develop with a 2x1440x900 setup, but I leave Firefox as a window at 1024x768 using Web Developer Toolbar.

The dual monitor setup is really useful when you have the code on one screen and Firefox on the other.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go over 800x600. However, ideally your layout is not fixed to a screen size, and can resize and still look right.

Comment: Most complex websites do use a fixed width though.  Not everyone has the CSS ninja skills required to make a design that expands and contracts with finesse.  Admittedly, it is becoming easier now that IE6 is almost dead.

Comment: @Skilldrick I don't like designing for 1024x768, because not all users like to have every web page maximized. So 800x600 is a reasonable compromise I think.

Answer (score 0):

I stick with 1024x768.  It's usually big enough for what you need to display, and not everyone is quite to 1600x1200 yet.  Maybe in a few years.  I'd stick with a smaller display...that way it may force you to be more design conscience.

Answer (score 0):

Two screens are invaluable regardless of screen size. One screen to run your editor, and one screen to run your browser. It's amazing how much smoother development becomes.

Answer (score 0):

With my stats showing 1024x768 as my users' dominant resolution, I certainly wouldn't go below that.  Beyond that, I agree with, apparently, everyone else here that fixed size layouts are just a bad idea, and your design should adapt to render context.

Answer (score 0):

For the love of Pete don't use pixel sized fonts. Use em or pt sizing instead.

It all really depends on what kind of page you are designing. I would try to design with the ability for the page to scale in mind. There is nothing I hate more than having to zoom in a page that was designed for 800x600 on a 1920x1200 display.

I think the best advice given here is just to try it at different resolutions instead of your native one, and try to make it look good at a variety of sizes.